# sql pesquisar registro em tabelas e retornar o nome da tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom, tenho a seguinte `query` **MySQL**;

```
    SELECT idMembro
    FROM membros 
    WHERE
       idMembro IN (
                  SELECT idMembro FROM pastores
            union SELECT idLider  FROM redes
            union SELECT idLider  FROM regioes
            union SELECT idLider  FROM areas
            union SELECT idLider  FROM setores
            union SELECT idLider  FROM celulas
       ) 
    ORDER BY nome
```

Meu objetivo é saber se o `idMembro` que eu procuro está presente em um dessas tabelas e, caso esteja, retorne o nome da tabela que foi encontrado o `idMembro`.

Caso não encontre, retorne `null`.

Por regra, um mesmo `idMembro` não pode estar em 2 tabelas ao mesmo tempo.

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veja essa querie utilizando sub consulta

```
 select t.idMembro, t.nomeTabela from (

          SELECT idMembro as idMembro, 'pastores' as  nomeTabela FROM pastores
    union SELECT idLider as idMembro, 'redes'   as  nomeTabela FROM redes
    union SELECT idLider as idMembro, 'regioes' as  nomeTabela FROM regioes
    union SELECT idLider as idMembro, 'areas'   as  nomeTabela FROM areas
    union SELECT idLider as idMembro, 'setores' as  nomeTabela FROM setores
    union SELECT idLider as idMembro, 'celulas' as  nomeTabela FROM celulas
) t
where t.idMembro = :idMebroConsultado
```

Substitua o :idMebroConsultado pelo o id que deseja, ou remova o where se quiser ver todos.

Veja a querie aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5da2e0/2

Comment: onde estará retornando o nome da tabela em que foi achado o id?

Comment: atualizei a consulta

Comment: observação, é MySQL ok. coloquei essa query no MySQL Front e deu erro

Comment: erro aqui:  :idMebroConsultado

Comment: Substitua o :idMebroConsultado pelo o id que deseja, ou remova o where se quiser ver todos.

Comment: nome tabela não é um campo  da tabela, mas sim o nome mesmo, tipo pastores, redes... Onde foi encontrado o registro.

Comment: sim,  o nome tabela foi um campo de tempo de execução que crie junto com joins na subquerie

Comment: está dando erro aqui: :idMebroConsultado mesmo quando troco por :idMembro

Comment: tira os 2 pontos na resposta ok? where t.idMembro = idMembro

Comment: não não substitua onde tem idMebro pelo número do id que você quer pesquisar exemplo: where t.idMembro = 1

Comment: no php fiz assim:   where t.idMembro = " . $_idMembro; onde $_idMembro é um parameto da função. Está certo?

Answer (score 2):

Experimente dessa forma (existem outras):

```
SELECT      ME.*
        ,   CASE WHEN PA.idMembro IS NOT NULL 
            THEN 'pastores'
            ELSE
            (   CASE WHEN RD.idLider IS NOT NULL 
                THEN 'redes'
                ELSE
                (   CASE WHEN RE.idLider IS NOT NULL 
                    THEN 'regioes'
                    ELSE
                    (   CASE WHEN AR.idLider IS NOT NULL 
                        THEN 'areas'
                        ELSE
                        (   CASE WHEN SE.idLider IS NOT NULL 
                            THEN 'setores'
                            ELSE
                            (   CASE WHEN CE.idLider IS NOT NULL 
                                THEN 'celulas'
                                END
                            )
                            END
                        )
                        END
                    )
                    END
                )
                END
            )
            END AS Tabela
FROM        membros     ME
LEFT JOIN   pastores    PA ON PA.idMembro = ME.idMembro
LEFT JOIN   redes       RD ON RD.idLider  = ME.idMembro
LEFT JOIN   regioes     RE ON RE.idLider  = ME.idMembro
LEFT JOIN   areas       AR ON AR.idLider  = ME.idMembro
LEFT JOIN   setores     SE ON SE.idLider  = ME.idMembro
LEFT JOIN   celulas     CE ON CE.idLider  = ME.idMembro
WHERE       PA.idMembro   IS NOT NULL
        OR  RD.idLider    IS NOT NULL
        OR  RE.idLider    IS NOT NULL
        OR  AR.idLider    IS NOT NULL
        OR  SE.idLider    IS NOT NULL
        OR  CE.idLider    IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY    ME.nome
```

---

Otimizando (e completando) a query do [@MarcianoMachado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/128359/marciano-machado), onde faltava a ligação com a tabela `membros`:

```
SELECT      ME.*
        ,   IFNULL(TMP.nomeTabela, '') AS Tabela
FROM        membros     ME
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT idMembro AS idMembro, 'pastores' AS  nomeTabela FROM pastores
                UNION 
                SELECT idLider  AS idMembro, 'redes'    AS  nomeTabela FROM redes
                UNION 
                SELECT idLider  AS idMembro, 'regioes'  AS  nomeTabela FROM regioes
                UNION 
                SELECT idLider  AS idMembro, 'areas'    AS  nomeTabela FROM areas
                UNION 
                SELECT idLider  AS idMembro, 'setores'  AS  nomeTabela FROM setores
                UNION
                SELECT idLider  AS idMembro, 'celulas'  AS  nomeTabela FROM celulas
            )           TMP ON TMP.idMembro = ME.idMembro
```

Comment: na outra consulta era onde NÃO estava o registro, já nessa, procuro por ele. Aliás, onde estará retornando o nome da tabela em que foi achado o id?

Comment: Ok, tem razão. Vou editar a resposta. A tabela será mostrada na coluna `Tabela`.

Comment: idResponsavel??? não tem idResponsavel

Comment: Xiii, pois é, _copy/paste_ mal feito! Resposta editada.

Comment: kkkk, acontece, mas, caso não se incomode, vou ficar com a query do outro colega que está mais simples de eu entender. Ok?

Comment: Claro. Estamos todos aqui para ajudar! De qualquer forma, se a resposta lhe foi útil em algum aspeto, dê um UP.

Comment: Resposta editada com _query_ complementar.